# How to close window in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, window

I want to close window using button cancel with spring controller and Java. Someone can help?

```
<input type="submit" value="cancel" action="cancel"/>
```

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "cancel")
    public String cancel(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
        //??
        return view.viewName;
    }
```

Comment: for doing that you will need to use javascript and not java

Comment: I am in same sitatuion where on click of cancel button i need to invalidate server session and close the current window.  
Here I am sending get request to logout controller and using Window.close (). it is invaliate my session and closing current window too.. but now it is lauching a new blank window..

anyone please help

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do it in JavaScript as @Satadru suggests. Something like this (untested):

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()"/>
```